# TSQL Parsing strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following string (an AD distinguished name):

`CN=Surname\, Firstname (something),OU=Fixed6,OU=Department99,OU=Fixed5,OU=Fixed4,DC=Fixed3,DC=Fixed2,DC=Fixed`

I need to parse "Department99" out of that (don't need the "OU=", and also don't necessarily need "Department", just the number).
The number 99 could be **any other integer**, and the number of fields to the right is fixed so it's **always** the 6th field from the right.

I would prefer the solution within a simple single SELECT statement with a correlated subquery, if it's possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one more way using split string available in 2016..

```
select replace(value,'OU=Department','')
 from string_split(@String,',')
where value like '%department%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a single `SELECT` solution:

```
declare @s nvarchar(max) = 'CN=Surname\, Firstname (something),OU=Fixed6,OU=Department56,OU=Fixed5,OU=Fixed4,DC=Fixed3,DC=Fixed2,DC=Fixed'

select reverse(left(reverse(left(@s, charindex(',', @s, charindex('department', @s, 0)) - 1)), patindex('%[a-zA-Z]%', reverse(left(@s, charindex(',', @s, charindex('department', @s, 0)) - 1)))-1))
```

This will work for most SQL Server versions.